# where is stored the icon informations for folders

Tags: nautilus

in nautilus you can change the icon of a folder, i need to know where is that data stored.. not the icon but the line that says nautilus to use some icon to some folder

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking.

Comment: **Welcome to AskUbuntu!**

Answer (score 2):

You likely find what you are looking for in the folder `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata`. Changes to items are written to files named after the folder containing the items.

Comment: This folder has binary files.. I can't read no one. Why? There's some other folder?