# How does Ubuntu know that I  have a folder icon customized?

Tags: icons, customization, info

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [where is stored the icon informations for folders](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42987/where-is-stored-the-icon-informations-for-folders)

In windows there's hidden a configuration file: if deleted, it's like it was never customized.

I don't see anything when customizing in Ubuntu,

**Where does it store the configuration file that says what icon to display?**

Comment: There's no .icons folder there.

Comment: I'm telling you, i have enabled the view of hidden folders/files, i see lots of .file/.folder but there's no .icons

Comment: OK ,then someone will answer it.

Comment: If you don't have a .icons folder create it, usually there's not .themes and .icons upon fresh install.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu stores directory information such as *what icon to display* in a user specific hidden folder. The folder is `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata`. Home directory settings are stored in `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home`. If you change some other settings on other partitions, they are stored also in this folder with a file name using partition UUID.

To Experiment with this, first move the folder in the Home directory and restart nautilus.

- Move the `gvfs-metadata` folder to home

  ```
  mv ~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata ~
  ```
- Restart nautilus by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and typing `nautilus -q`. Then again bring the dash command with the previous keyboard shortcut and type `nautilus`. You will see that, any customized icon is reset to default.
- Now again move the `gvfs-metadata` to it's previous location

  ```
  mv ~/gvfs-metadata ~/.local/share/
  ```

  Again, restart nautilus by doing `nautilus -q` command and open your home folder to see that, the customized icon is now back!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what DE you're using your settings will be in hidden folders such as:

Folders starting with:

- Gnome : .gnome2, etc.
- KDE: .kde

Others are inside the .config folder such as:

- XFCE: .xfce4, etc.

Answer (score 0):

While this doesnt answer your specific question, ýou may benefit from learning more about the file system in Ubuntu.  This previous question, [**"How to Understand the Ubuntu file system layout"**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138547/how-to-understand-the-ubuntu-file-system-layout) is a terriffic source for just that (and somewhere in there, is you answer).